# bxslider Get current slider ID name

Tags: slider, bxslider, caption

In a page we are using more then 5 Bx Slider, we need to get the current slider ID name (ss1 or ss2). I need use pass this id on

**onSlideBefore:**

```
function(){ 
//current slider id name
get current slider name
test (current slider ID);
}
```

see below.

```
<ul class="bxslider" id="ss1" >
      <li> hfh</li>
      <li> hfh</li>
  </ul>
<ul class="bxslider" id="ss1">
      <li> hfh</li>
      <li> hfh</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: or i need bx slider caption should not slide, i want the captions should be sticky ( sticky background). on horizontal slide i need to change only text on the bx captions.

Comment: >we need to get the current slider ID name (ss1 or ss2)< that would depend on what? Both sliders exist already, did you mean id on the current slide(`<li>`)? >or i need bx slider caption should not slide, i want the captions should be sticky ( sticky background)< ok, that sounds straight forward. >on horizontal slide i need to change only text on the bx captions.< You just said you want the captions not to slide **BUT** you want them to change? So you mean you want captions to fade in and out? 0_0???